# Name of image in drawable folder red

Tags: android

I have just added a new image (.png) into my drawable folder for an app I'm working on, and the name of the image appears as red. In previous apps I've made the name appears the same color as the rest of the files/folders. The app recognizes the image fine and I use it as an launch icon, which also works fine. I'm just curious as to why it is red, and how I could go about making it a normal color.

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to post an image of what I'm talking about, so if I was unclear on anything I'm happy to clarify!

EDIT: Here is a photo:

[image]

Comment: Please post a LINK to your image

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you using a version control system? On my Android Studio setup, red files are files that have not yet been added to git.

Comment: Ahh yes that seems to have been it!! Thank you very much! I'm using Git. I shall mark this as the answer in 9 minutes when it lets me =)

Comment: No problem. It took me awhile to figure out what the colors mean too. Green means added but not yet committed. Blue means changed since last commit.

Comment: Thanks for this! red means ERROR in most interfaces so I was 100% sure I was doing something wrong